# Print raw EPL using Zebra GC420t(EPL) using windows "Generic Text Only" driver

Tags: windows, printing, zebra-printers

Strange that I'm able to print raw ZPL commands but not EPL commands using windows Generic Text Only driver through GC420t(EPL) machine.the below is the raw EPLfile exported from .lbl file.But on printing it does nothing.

```
I8,A,001


Q799,024
q863
rN
S3
D7
ZT
JF
O
R32,0
f100
N
B445,62,0,1,4,12,78,B,"AB"
A471,162,0,4,6,8,N,"AB"
A447,305,0,2,2,2,N,"Rh POSITIVE"
B451,456,0,1,2,6,82,B,"08/01/2015"
A450,431,0,4,1,1,N,"Expiry Date"
A456,574,0,4,1,1,N,"12/08/89"
B64,69,0,1,3,9,82,B,"123"
A67,564,0,2,2,2,N,"Whole Blood"
B69,458,0,1,2,6,79,B,"Whole Blood"
A67,615,0,1,1,1,N,"prepared from 450ml of "
A71,635,0,1,1,1,N,"whole blood"
A69,658,0,1,1,1,N,"stora at 4c to 5c"
A69,679,0,1,1,1,N,"transport at 5c to 10c"
A62,52,0,1,1,1,N,"DIN"
A65,207,0,2,1,1,N,"Date Bled"
TDdd/mn/y2
B67,225,0,1,2,6,84,B,TD
A67,337,0,4,1,1,N,"12 FEB 89"
A67,369,0,1,1,1,N,"Properly Identify Intended"
A69,388,0,1,1,1,N,"Recipient"
P1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue with EPL commands getting through with the Generic/Text driver.

I used the Seagull Scientific, Zebra printer driver.  After install go to Printing Preferences ->  Page Setup tab -> Advanced Options -> Pass Through tab.  Set to "Generic/Text Only" mode and check the "Add CR/LF" box at the bottom.  Worked great after that.